# PHP Curl Json Filtering

Tags: php, json, api, php-curl

So basically I have taken over a client's website and Autotrader has made some changes to their API. I can no longer filter out the results with a link. I have never in my life used PHP Curl and the furthest I have gone with PHP is Form validation.

**This is the old code I could use:**

```
      public function list_cars($count = 8, $page = 1)
{
    $core = new Core();
    $cars = $core->send_request('/service/stock-management/search?advertisingLocation=autotraderCars&advertiserId=' . $core->advertiser_id . '&pageSize=' . $count . '&page=' . $page);

    
    return json_decode($cars);

    

}
```

**This is the new code I have to use:**

```
      public function list_cars($count = 8, $page = 1)
{
    $core = new Core();
    $cars = $core->send_request('/service/stock-management/stock?&advertiserId=' . $core->advertiser_id . '&pageSize=' . $count . '&page=' . $page);

    
    return json_decode($cars);

    

}
```

My problem is that with the new code it is displaying all of the previous Ads for cars that are no longer on the website (Data must still be held even after a car sale)

**In order to filter through the ads i need to do this:**

```
    "adverts": {
         "retailAdverts": {
             "autotraderAdvert": {
                   "status": "PUBLISHED"

            }
```

How on earth do I translate this into PHP Curl??

This is the line of code i have almost been certain i need to add but im so far from correct:

```
    json_decode($cars)->adverts->retailAdverts->autotraderAdvert->status == 'PUBLISHED'
```

The response below is from a full lookup submission

```
    {
"vehicle": {
    "ownershipCondition": "Used",
    "registration": "AB12CDE",
    "vin": "WAUZXXXXXXXXX12345",
    "make": "Audi",
    "model": "A4",
    "generation": null,
    "derivative": "2.0 TDI ultra S line Saloon 4dr Diesel Manual (109 g/km, 161 bhp)",
    "derivativeId": "09ab072a937c3594b5e8c64251bde2eb",
    "vehicleType": "Car",
    "trim": "S line",
    "bodyType": "Saloon",
    "fuelType": "Diesel",
    "cabType": null,
    "transmissionType": "Manual",
    "wheelbaseType": null,
    "roofHeightType": null,
    "drivetrain": "Front Wheel Drive",
    "seats": 5,
    "doors": 4,
    "co2EmissionGPKM": 109,
    "topSpeedMPH": 140,
    "zeroToSixtyMPHSeconds": 8.3,
    "zeroToOneHundredKMPHSeconds": 8.4,
    "badgeEngineSizeLitres": 2.0,
    "engineCapacityCC": 1968,
    "enginePowerBHP": 161,
    "fuelCapacityLitres": 63.0,
    "emissionClass": "Euro 6",
    "owners": 1,
    "fuelEconomyNEDCExtraUrbanMPG": 74.3,
    "fuelEconomyNEDCUrbanMPG": 56.5,
    "fuelEconomyNEDCCombinedMPG": null,
    "fuelEconomyWLTPLowMPG": null,
    "fuelEconomyWLTPMediumMPG": null,
    "fuelEconomyWLTPHighMPG": null,
    "fuelEconomyWLTPExtraHighMPG": null,
    "fuelEconomyWLTPCombinedMPG": null,
    "bootSpaceSeatsUpLitres": 480.0,
    "insuranceGroup": "29",
    "insuranceSecurityCode": "E",
    "firstRegistrationDate": "2015-09-15",
    "colour": "Black",
    "style": null,
    "subStyle": null,
    "lengthMM": 4701,
    "heightMM": 1427,
    "widthMM": 2040,
    "payloadLengthMM": null,
    "payloadWidthMM": null,
    "payloadHeightMM": null,
    "payloadWeightKG": null,
    "minimumKerbWeightKG": 1540,
    "grossVehicleWeightKG": null,
    "cylinders": 4,
    "bootSpaceSeatsDownLitres": 962.0,
    "odometerReadingMiles": null,
    "motExpiryDate": null,
    "warrantyMonthsOnPurchase": null,
    "serviceHistory": null,
    "plate": "65",
    "yearOfManufacture": "2015",
    "interiorCondition": null,
    "tyreCondition": null,
    "bodyCondition": null,
    "exDemo": null,
    "keys": null,
    "v5Certificate": null,
    "previousOwners": null,
    "driverPosition": null,
    "axleConfiguration": null,
    "upholstery": null,
    "interiorColour": null,
    "exteriorFinish": null,
    "lastServiceOdometerReadingMiles": null,
    "lastServiceDate": null,
    "chassisMake": null,
    "chassisModel": null,
    "bedroomLayout": null,
    "endLayout": null,
    "bedrooms": null,
    "berths": null,
    "standard": {
        "make": "Audi",
        "model": "A4",
        "generation": null,
        "derivative": null,
        "trim": "S line",
        "bodyType": "Saloon",
        "fuelType": "Diesel",
        "transmissionType": "Manual",
        "cabType": null,
        "drivetrain": "Front Wheel Drive",
        "colour": "Black",
        "style": null,
        "subStyle": null
    }
},
"advertiser": {
    "advertiserId": "66897"
},
"adverts": {
    "forecourtPrice": {
        "amountGBP": null
    },
    "purchasePrice": {
        "amountGBP": null
    },
    "preparationCosts": {
        "amountGBP": null
    },
    "dueDate": null,
    "stockInDate": null,
    "stockInValue": {
        "amountGBP": null
    },
    "soldDate": null,
    "soldPrice": {
        "amountGBP": null
    },
    "buyerPostcode": null,
    "manufacturerApproved": null,
    "twelveMonthsMot": null,
    "motInsurance": null,
    "reservationStatus": null,
    "retailAdverts": {
          "price": {
            "amountGBP": 10498
          },
          "totalPrice": {
            "amountGBP": 10598
          },
          "adminFee": {
            "amountGBP": 100
          },
        "priceOnApplication": null,
        "manufacturerRRP": {
            "amountGBP": null
        },
        "vatExcluded": false,
        "attentionGrabber": null,
        "description": null,
        "description2": null,
        "autotraderAdvert": {
            "status": "NOT_PUBLISHED"
        },
        "advertiserAdvert": {
            "status": "NOT_PUBLISHED"
        },
        "locatorAdvert": {
            "status": "NOT_PUBLISHED"
        },
        "exportAdvert": {
            "status": "NOT_PUBLISHED"
        },
        "profileAdvert": {
            "status": "NOT_PUBLISHED"
        },
        "displayOptions": {
            "excludePreviousOwners": false,
            "excludeStrapline": false,
            "excludeMot": false,
            "excludeWarranty": false,
            "excludeInteriorDetails": false,
            "excludeTyreCondition": false,
            "excludeBodyCondition": false
        }
    }
},
"metadata": {
    "stockId": "2c9299d1744ec0a90174587a2fbb3524",
    "searchId": "202009043303511",
    "externalStockId": null,
    "externalStockReference": null,
    "lastUpdated": "2020-09-04T09:37:16.731Z",
    "lastUpdatedByAdvertiser": "2020-09-04T09:37:16.728Z",
    "versionNumber": 1,
    "lifecycleState": "FORECOURT",
    "dateOnForecourt": "2020-09-04"
},
"features": [],
"media": {
    "videoUrl": null,
    "images": []
}
```

}

Comment: your example of old and new code are the same, edit your question.

Comment: They arent, check where i am sending the request, I can no longer use "/service/stock-management/search?advertisingLocation=autotraderCars&advertiserId="

Comment: You could use array_filter on the return data to get rid of stuff you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is not with PHP Curl - it is returning your object results correctly.

It sounds like you only want to return the result if the status is PUBLISHED. To accomplish this you would do something like this:

```
<?php
      public function list_cars($count = 8, $page = 1)
{
    $core = new Core();
    $cars = $core->send_request('/service/stock-management/stock?&advertiserId=' . $core->advertiser_id . '&pageSize=' . $count . '&page=' . $page);

//    return json_decode($cars);


   $results = json_decode($cars, true);

   $status = $results['adverts']['retailAdverts']['advertiserAdvert']['status'];
   
   if($status == 'PUBLISHED')
   {
        //return object data
       $results = $results;
   }
   else
   {
       //return nothing
        $results = null;
   }

   return $results;
   
}

?>
```

Comment: This is assuming that there is only one object returned from your json results as shown in your example. If you are receiving many listings, you would need to do a for each loop to only return the published listings.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain, where would the loop go?

Comment: Can you post your full JSON response showing more than one listing -- Also can you confirm what your desired result is -  do you want to return an array of results that are published only?

Comment: The full JSON response is that * however many cars are listed, so that * 14.

Comment: I am wanting to go through every car and check if it is PUBLISHED or NOT_PUBLISHED, if PUBLISHED I want it to be shown, if NOT_PUBLISHED I dont want it to be shown.

Comment: The list of cars is $cars and each individual car is $car

Comment: So i have "foreach ($cars as $car){" but unsure as to where to put it. All info goes into already made templates, 1 template for the list and another for each car to have its own page.

Comment: So you run this CURL command several times to return a Json response each time OR does the Json have multiple items that it returns? Would need to see this to help.